# 'arecord' works but FFMPEG 'cannot open audio device'

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg, alsa

On my Linux-based QNAP NAS, I can successfully record my Loopback audio device using:

```
# arecord -D default:CARD=Loopback test.wav
```

However, FFMPEG cannot use this same audio device. It returns:

```
    [alsa @ 0x5a45880] cannot open audio device hw:default:CARD=Loopback (No such file or directory)
hw:default:CARD=Loopback: Input/output error
```

I've also tried any number of `hw:` options in FFMPEG. For what it's worth, the arecord -l command returns:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC262 Analog [ALC262 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Loopback [Loopback], device 0: Loopback PCM [Loopback PCM]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Loopback [Loopback], device 1: Loopback PCM [Loopback PCM]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

arecord -L returns:

```
[~] # arecord -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
sysdefault:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC262 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC262 Analog
    Front speakers
sysdefault:CARD=Loopback
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
```

FFMPEG command and response is:

```
[~] # /share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.qpkg/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:default:CARD=Loopback test.mp3
ffmpeg version 4.2.1-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
ALSA lib ../../../src/pcm/pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM hw:default:CARD=Loopback
[alsa @ 0x5f64800] cannot open audio device hw:default:CARD=Loopback (No such file or directory)
hw:default:CARD=Loopback: Input/output error
```

FFMPEG -sources alsa gives:

```
[~] # /share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.qpkg/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -sources alsa
ffmpeg version 4.2.1-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Auto-detected sources for alsa:
ALSA lib ../../../src/control/control.c:1375:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL hw:0
Cannot list sources.
```

Can anyone shed some light on why this is impossible in FFMPEG and suggest what I'm doing wrong here? FFMPEG includes the ALSA module, and is version 4.2.1. Thanks!

Comment: Try `ffmpeg -f alsa -i sysdefault:CARD=Loopback test.mp3`

Comment: That gives the same result unfortunately

Comment: Show output of `ffmpeg -sources alsa`

Comment: Thanks, I've added that to my question. It doesn't like it..

Comment: Works for me using same build (4.2.1 from John). Try compiling `ffmpeg` to exclude possible issues from John's builds. Or at least try the latest git master version from johnvansickle.com.

Comment: Thanks - tried both git and release versions from John (good tip, thanks) but no dice. Am now trying it in a virtual Ubuntu machine and having a little more luck. It's frustrating to not know the cause but I guess it is a half-broken, half-modified ALSA stump in the QNAP OS. Their support suggested the Ubuntu VM, so I guess that's that. Thanks very much for your help.